# Inserir varios dados em uma coluna mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Boa tarde Galera, estou quebrando a cabeça de como faço essa inserçao no banco, é mais ou menos assim...

Eu tenho um produto, que precisa ter preço de mais de um fornecedor, para comparar os preços. Mas a minha quantidade de fornecedor depende da quantidade cadastrada, nao tenho um numero fixo.

Até o momento eu tenho duas tabelas, uma tabale fornecedor, aonde eu cadastro os fornecedores, e uma tabela produtos, aonde cadastro os produtos e relaciono com a tabela fornecedor, atraves da chave estrangeira id_fornecedor.

Agradeço desde ja!.

Answer (score 1):

Você vai precisar de uma tabela associativa.
Uma vez que um produto precisa se relacionar com muitos fornecedores e um fornecedor pode ter muitos produtos.

Nessa tabela associativa você pode ter um as colunas `ID`, `ID_PROD`, `ID_FORN`, `PRECO`.

Dessa forma, você consegue resolver seu problema.
Pra cada preço oferecido por cada fornecedor, você pode preencher essa tabela com o ID do produto, o ID do fornecedor e qual o preço daquele item.

*DICA: Normalmente se cria a tabela de item_produto.
Neste item, pode ter inclusive a quantidade de produto, mas não sei se é interessante pra você no momento.*

Comment: Andrew Ribeiro, deixa eu ver se entendi, no caso, eu criaria a tabela item_produto, com os campos id, id_prod, id_forn, preco. Aonde id_prod se relaciona com o campo id da minha tabela produtos, e o id_forn se relaciona com o campo id da minha tabela fornecedores. Aí eu teria que excluir a minha chave estrangeira que ja tenho na tabela produtos, certo?

Comment: agora está assim...

minha tabela item_produtos está com _id_produto_ relacionando a tabela de produtos e _id_fornecedor_ relacionando a tabela fornecedor.

coloquei um inner join para mostrar os dados no php, mas nao esta funcionando..
`

$query = "SELECT * FROM `item_produtos`
INNER JOIN `fornecedor` ON `fornecedor.id` =`item_produtos`.`id_fornecedor`
INNER JOIN `materiais` ON `materiais.id` = `item_produtos`.`id_produtos`";
$dados = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
$linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dados);
$total = mysqli_num_rows($dados);
`

Comment: É exatamente isso.
Você vai excluir o chave estrangeira da tabela produto por que agora você tem uma tabela associativa.
Dai o select ficaria mais ou menos assim:
`select * from item_produto join produto on produto.id = item_produto.id_produto join fornecedor on fornecedor.id = item_produto.id_fornecedor;`
Tente executar esse SQL diretamente no console do banco de dados, deverá funcionar.
Caso seu erro persista, crie outra pergunta especificamente sobre a linguagem, no caso PHP.